# Find all descendants

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

So I am studying for a midterm and am stuck on parts 1 and 3 of this practice question.

Consider the following relation:

Family(parent, child, childDOB)

The intent  is  that    a   tuple   (p,c,d) means   that    parent  p has   child   c,  who was born    on
date    d.  You may assume  that    parents do  not have    two children    of  the same    name,
and that    there   are no  twins;  i.e.,   no  parent  has two or  more    children    born    on  the 
same    day.    Here    are three   queries we  might   ask about   this    data:

I. Find for each    parent, the youngest    child,  i.e.,   the set of  (p,c)   such    that    p has
child   c,  and no  other   child   of  p has   a   smaller date    of  birth   than    c does.

II. Find    the set of  great   grandparents    of  “Amy.”

III. Find   all the descendants of  “Mike.”

Which   of  the above   queries are expressible in  relational  algebra?

So far for the first one I have this:

```
select
from family
group by parent
```

so now I know I have the groups of parents but I don't know how to select just the youngest child

I got the second one by using 2 subqueries, but for the third one I don't think I can do that again because there is no guarantee on how many generations his descendants span, so I'm stuck on that one I don't have anything for that one yet

For the last part about which can be expressed with relational algebra...is it all of them? Can all SQL be translated into relational algebra?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If this was in Oracle, I would use hierarchical queries (`START WITH`, `CONNECT BY`). Try to look for something similar in postgre

Comment: If this was SO then I would expect a table creation statement, some test data as insert statements, and some expected results. And your attempt at a query to answer the question. ;-/ That we can help you with. see [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: I mean I guess I could create a table, and test data, but I think the goal of the question is to come up with a generic query that would work on any table that follows the relation Family(parent, child, childDOB) and not just one table

Comment: Ok, Did the lecturer give you any clues as to how to go about solving this? did you get any notes and test data? It isn't our job to make test data for you.

Comment: not particular hints for this question, no. We have learned select, from, where, group by, order by, having, and aggregate functions, so I guess I do know that I still need to probably find a place to put a min() function to find the youngest child

Comment: I don't think anyone needs to make test data to solve this problem

Comment: How do you know your query will work unless you run it against some test data? For Example given 3 records how do you know your query selects the correct child? Then given 100 records how do you know it works?

Comment: I guess I wouldn't know really, but I would ideally have very strong arguments as to why my query is correct

Comment: The database is deaf. It runs your query and returns a list of rows. How do you know the list is correct?

Comment: When you pull up a bank balance - it would be nice to know it is correct? We don't really want to discuss with someone  about the accuracy of it because it wasn't tested very well?

Comment: I mean I understand that I wouldn't know with 100% certainty that the query worked unless I had test data, but I think it is satisfactory to have solid theoretical arguments as to why a query would work for any table. I could make the same argument that how do I know the query that worked with one set of test data will work for all other test data?

Comment: I have run out of useful suggestions. It was interesting talking with you. Seriously, was useful and a reminder to me. Come back if you have other issues.

Comment: Okay thank you, I have taken your suggestion into consideration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursive-query+postgresql

Comment: This is also covered in the Postgres manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html